# Scala: what is the purpose of 'override'

Tags: scala

I'm not sure what the purpose of `override` keyword is, in scala. If I have

```
trait Shape { def foo(v: Int) }
class Triangle extends Shape { override def foo(v: Int) {} }
```

it behaves (apparently at least) exactly the same as it does without `override`.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In the case you are implementing an abstract method as in your example, it is not strictly necessary to add the `override` modifier.

However, in case you want to `override` a concrete method from the superclass, the `override` modifier is necessary. This is to avoid accidental overrides which could happen with mixing composition -- mixing-in traits during some refactoring could easily introduce a method definition that could be overridden by the method defined in the body of the class, hence the need for explicitly stating that a method is an override.

Answer (score 35):

In your particular case, you got a comprehensive answer from axel22. I just want to add, that there is at least one more case where you may encounter override modifier. The keyword can also be used with trait methods.

Imagine that you have an abstract class:

```
abstract class Writer {
  def print(str: String)
}
```

and its concrete implementation that prints on a console

```
class ConsoleWriter extends Writer {
  def print(str: String) = println(str)
}
```

Now, you want to create a trait that will modify its behaviour. Look at the following implementation:

```
trait Uppercase extends Writer {
  abstract override def print(str: String) = 
    super.print(str.toUpperCase())
}
```

Notice that a method has two modifiers: abstract and override. This is only allowed for traits and  it means that the trait must be mixed into some class that has a concrete definition of the method in question

With the definition above, you can do:

```
val writer = new ConsoleWriter with Uppercase
writer.print("abc")
```

which will yield the result

ABC

Much in the same vain, you can add more traits:

```
trait WithSpaces extends Writer {
  abstract override def print(str: String) = 
    super.print(str.split("").mkString(" ").tail)
}
```

Now when you call

```
val writer = new ConsoleWriter with Uppercase with WithSpaces
writer.print("abc")
```

you will see:

A B C

The above usage of an override modifier in traits is a distinguishing feature in scala and you won't see it in java.

Comment: Fantastic explanation of Scala traits!

Answer (score 10):

It's for error checking.
Suppose you have

```
trait Shape { def foo(v: Int) = 1 }
class Triangle extends Shape { override def foo(v: Int) = 2 }
```

and then you change Shape to

```
trait Shape { def bar(v: Int) = 1 }
```

In that case the "override" will tell you that the `foo` in `Triangle` overrides nothing.

See also:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicit_overrides_and_final

Comment: That's only correct if the method that was overriden was abstract, see axel22 s answer.

Also, both of your links are irrelevant because they apply to Java and C++, not Scala in particular.

Comment: Cubic, it does not matter whether the overriden method is abstract, this can change with time. The interface change, the override helps to stay in tune.

Comment: Your answer implies that the override keyword behaves the same as the `@Override` annotation in Java. That's only correct when overriding abstract methods.

Comment: Cubic, `trait Shape { def bar(v: Int) }; class Triangle extends Shape { override def foo(v: Int) = 2 }` gives an error "method foo overrides nothing", it has nothing to do with whether the `bar` is abstract or not.

Comment: For example, you could implement a method `bar` in Triangle and then decide to add abstract method `bar` to Shape and then remove abstract method `foo`. The `foo` in Triangle will then "override nothing", even though the `foo` in Shape was abstract.

Comment: I'm talking about what happens when you _don't_ use the override keyword. Using your example `trait Shape { def bar(v : Int) = 1}; class Triangle extends Shape { def bar(v : Int) = 2}` won't compile. I'm saying your answer neglects to mention this.

Comment: Cubic, true. My answer is about the *purpose* of the `override`, not about the Scala requirements on where to use it.  ; )